# X has 972 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 6804 features as input

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, classification, jupyter, knn

I am having a problem with my KNN fruit classification. I have a dataset of fresh and rotten oranges the training data has 1000 fresh and 1000 rotten oranges images and my test data has 300 fresh and rotten oranges. Now, when I tried to implement KNN on my python code I got the error.

> ValueError: X has 972 features, but KNeighborsClassifier is expecting 6804 features as input.

Here's my code:

FOR TRAINING DATA:

```
training_fresh = []

for entry in glob.glob("path"):
    img=np.array(mpimg.imread(entry))
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(64,128))
    fd = hog(resized_img,channel_axis=2)
    training_fresh.append(fd)

training_rotten = []

for entry in glob.glob("path"):
    img=np.array(mpimg.imread(entry))
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(64,128))
    fd = hog(resized_img,channel_axis=2)
    training_rotten.append(fd)

train_data = training_rotten + training_fresh
```

FOR LABELS:

```
train_label_list = []

for i in range(len(train_data)):
    if i < 1000:
        train_label_list.append(0)
    else:
        train_label_list.append(1)
print(train_label_list)
print(len(train_label_list))
```

FOR LABELED TEST DATA:

```
test_fresh = []
for entry in glob.glob("PATH"):
    img = np.array(mpimg.imread(entry))
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(64,32))
    fd = hog(resized_img, channel_axis=2)
    test_dict = {'data':fd, 'label':1}
    test_fresh.append(test_dict)

test_rotten = []
for entry in glob.glob("PATH"):
    img = np.array(mpimg.imread(entry))
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img,(64,32))
    fd = hog(resized_img, channel_axis=2)
    test_dict = {'data':fd, 'label':0}
    test_rotten.append(test_dict)

test_data = test_rotten + test_fresh
```

FOR SEPARATION OF DATA FROM LABELS:

```
test_features = []
test_labels = []

for i in test_data:
    test_labels.append(i['label'])
    test_features.append(i['data'])
```

Everything went fine. But, after I tried to run this KNN implementation I got the Error:

```
x_axis_k_points = []

#LIST OF MATRICES
f1 = []
accuracy = []
confusion_matrix = []

for k in range(7):
    #KNN CLASSIFIER 
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k+1)
    knn.fit(train_data, train_label_list)

    #KNN CLASSIFIER PREDICTION
    pred_labels = knn.predict(test_features)

    #ACCURACY
    acs = knn.score(test_features, test_labels)
    accuracy.append(acs)

    #CONFUSION MATRIX
    confusion_matrix.append(metrics.confusion_matrix(test_labels, pred_labels))

    #F1 SCORE
    f1.append(metrics.f1_score(test_labels, pred_labels, pos_label=1))

    x_axis_k_points.append(k+1)
```

Please help me. Because the deadline of this project is tomorrow. Any help will do. I just don't get it why I am having the error. I tried rerunning my code and fixing my dataset but still the problem exists. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you also add `train_data.shape` and `train_label_list.shape`?

Comment: You should work with DataFrames / Matrices , not simple lists. Lists are 1D so not good for a X matrice and y vector.

Comment: @sotmot unfortunately I can't even run train_data.shape because it is a list it returns an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'.

Comment: what would you suggest to edit in my code @Malo

Comment: you could try np.array(data) to convert it to an array , you can then use reshape(..) to make it the shape you need

Comment: @JustPeter, try `a = np.array(train_data)` and then `a.shape` maybe?

Comment: you could include some of your data so we can easily reproduce and suggest some code

Comment: @sotmot it actually worked and now it revealed that my train_data has (2000, 6804) shape and I don't know how did it become so big.

Comment: After re reading your code, I noticed you are doing different things with train_data and test_data. They should be handled the same way. I think the special way you handle test_data cause the difference. Instead of pred_labels = knn.predict(test_features)   ....  try pred_labels = knn.predict(test_data).

Comment: Also acs = knn.score(test_features, test_labels) should be acs = knn.score(test_data, pred_labels)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So, the problem is clear now. It is a dimension mismatch.

- For the training data, the preprocessing is done as: `cv2.resize(img,(64,128))`
- For the testing data, the preprocessing is done as: `cv2.resize(img,(64,32))`.

This causes a change in the data size. Ensure that the resizes are the same and try `fit` and `predict` again.